# How can I get a jQuery UI Dialog to display as a Dialog (instead of being pinned to the bottom of the page)?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Using the idea [here](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/) as a "proof-of-concept" before replacing the html with my own, I added html adapted from that to my Index.cshtml file (ASP.NET MVC app):

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Important information">
    <span class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span></span>
    <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
        <label>
            Add additional Email:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="addlemail" />
        <button id="btnSaveAddlEmail">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this jQuery in the Scripts section of that file to open that div (the previous plain-vanilla alert in the click handler is shown commented out):

```
$('#dialog-message').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx'
});

$("#btnAddlEmail").click(function () {
    //var email = prompt('Please enter the email address', 'name@provider.com');
    //if (null != email) //&& (email != "name@provider.com")
    //{
    //    alert(email);
    //}
    $('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
}); // $("#btnAddlEmail").click(function ()
```

However, when I click "+ Add Another Email", the "dialog" just displays at the bottom of the page, rather than in a modal dialog:

[image]

(I also don't know from whence that "Close" button emanates).

Note: I have (presumably, anyway) done what is necessary to make jQuery UI work in my project, following the steps [here](http://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127017/where-are-the-bundles-for-jquery-ui-css-and-scripts-and-what-exactly-are-they-na).

What hoop do I have to hop through to get the dialog to act as a modal dialog, instead of a bump on a log file?

### UPDATE

I added the script references below the following in the \Home\Index.cshtml file:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: The code you have shown works fine (refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be297ag6/1/)). If your not getting the dialog, then you have not included the relevant scripts and/or css files for jquery-ui.

Comment: I guess I don't know where to add them; I tried adding them directly below the Scripts section in the .cshtml file, but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to edit your question to show where your loading the scripts and css files.

Comment: Your edit does not show that your loading any scripts. Inside your `@section Scripts {` you need to include `jquery-{version}.js` and `jquery-ui.js`, and then you also need include the relevant css files.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: put your div at the top in the main content area so that it renders above the other content

also to get the dialog to display make sure you included the css for the modal

Comment: It makes no difference where in the html I put it; it was at the bottom of the html section (of the Index.cshtml file), I moved it to the top, but the behavior is exactly the same in either place.